# Not able to export CLOB data from hive to db2

Tags: db2, hive, sqoop

I am successfully able to import data with clob data type from db2 to hive. After some processing on table in hive, I want to load back the table to db2.

Command used to import:

```
$SQOOP_HOME/bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:db2://192.168.145.64:50000/one --table clobtest --username db2inst1 --password dbuser --hive-import --map-column-hive CLOBB=STRING --inline-lob-limit 155578 --target-dir /tmp/1 --m 1
```

Command used to export:

```
$SQOOP_HOME/bin/sqoop export --connect jdbc:db2://192.168.145.64:50000/one --username db2inst1 --password dbuser --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/clobtest --table clobtest --input-fields-terminated-by '\0001' --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' --m 1
```

At the time of export, I am getting below error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not buffer record
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:84)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException: com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.ClobRef
    at java.lang.Object.clone(Native Method)
    at org.apache.sqoop.lib.LobRef.clone(LobRef.java:109)
    at clobtest.clone(clobtest.java:222)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:213)
    ... 15 more
```

Any idea about this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: @shawn I was able to import the BLOB type of columns in string in hive.  $SQOOP_HOME/bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.41.67:1521/orcl --username orcluser1 --password impetus --table test --hive-import  --map-column-java "logs=String" --map-column-hive "logs=String" --m 1 -verbose   This command worked. logs is my column name and it is of type blob. You have to map LOB type of columns to String in  --map-column-java  comma separated if multiple lob column are there.